# ML Model is not reloaded after it is retrained (Only if prediction was made before)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ml.net

I want trained machine learning model to be automatically reloaded after a new version is available, so I set `watchForChanges` to `true`:

```
services.AddPredictionEnginePool<SentimentData, SentimentPrediction>()
                  .FromFile(
                  modelName: Constants.ModelName,
                  filePath: Constants.ModelFileName,
                  watchForChanges: true);
```

It seems that it works only if prediction is not made before model is retrained.

This is an exception I see in events:

[image]

Should I do something else to get desired result?

You can see sample project demonstrating this issue: https://github.com/alexandermujirishvili/DotnetMLWatchForChanges/tree/master

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible

But you can create a factory class for look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63736588/is-it-possible-to-add-a-service-from-a-controller-or-manager-class-other-than-th)
and with object pool design pattern

```
 public class PredictionEngineObjPool<T>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentBag<T> _objects;
    private readonly Func<T> _objectGenerator;

    public PredictionEngineObjPool(Func<T> objectGenerator)
    {
        _objectGenerator = objectGenerator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(objectGenerator));
        _objects = new ConcurrentBag<T>();
    }

    public T Get()
    {
        var result = _objects.TryTake(out T item) ? item : _objectGenerator();

        return result;
    }

    public void Return(T item)
    {
        _objects.Add(item);
    }
}
```

then create a manager

```
 public class PredictionManager
{
    public Tdest Predict<Tsrc, Tdest>(string modelName,Tsrc example) where Tsrc : class where Tdest : class, new()
    {
        var mlContext = new MLContext();
       //create your engine
    }
}
```

use in your program

```
var pool = new PredictionEngineObjPool<PredictionManager>(() => new PredictionManager());

var _predictionManager = pool.Get();

var  prediction= _predictionManager.Predict<ModelInput, ModelOutput>("name", input);
```

Comment: It will be fixed in a new release. https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/5350