# Is it possible to add a service from a controller or manager class other than the ConfigureService method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, ml.net

I want to Use

```
services.AddPredictionEnginePool<..>
```

When I use "IServiceCollection DI" I receive the notification below

Cannot instantiate implementation type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection' for service type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection'.

How can I Use this;

```
services.AddPredictionEnginePool<..>
```

From other classes.

Why I want do;

The reason of the usage of the service is to add a new object in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IServiceCollection` is the configuration of the DI container; you're not supposed to used it at runtime. At most, one would use `IServiceProvider` (using it as a Service Locator), but that can also be seen as an anti-pattern when using DI.

Without more context on the exact thing you're trying to accomplish, I'd suggest using some sort of factory class that knows how the create those objects at runtime (based on some data/config), and inject the factory where needed.

https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html